# iOS Swift: video thumbnail error

Tags: swift, error-handling, avplayer, video-thumbnails

I'm creating video thumbnails with the following code and it works in most cases. However sometimes it throws an error and the thumbnail is not created. I can't figure out why it does not work sometimes.

Here is how I create video thumbnail:

```
let asset = AVAsset(URL: url)
let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

do {
    let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(CMTimeMake(1, 30), actualTime: nil)
    let uiImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
    imageview.image = uiImage  
}
catch let error as NSError
{
    print("Image generation failed with error \(error)")
}
```

It works in most cases, when it does not work it throws this error:

```
Error generating thumbnail: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x17658520 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12792 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12792)}
```

I have no clue why it throws this error and did not find any solution on stack overflow even though other people faced same problem.

Comment: Any solution found for this ?

Comment: Hi Did any one find any solution for this?

Comment: Still facing this issue...any solution out there?

Comment: have you found answer for this?

Comment: Anyone found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
func generateThumbnail(path: URL) -> UIImage? {
            do {
                let asset = AVURLAsset(url: path, options: nil)
                let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
                imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
                let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: nil)
                let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
                return thumbnail
            } catch let error {
                print("*** Error generating thumbnail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return nil
            }
        }
```

Comment: i have used the same code but same error. Although the video is correct